# Програмное изменение jpg или png изображения, без изменения его отображения

Tags: c#, изображения

Добрый вечер.
Поступила следующая задача. Рандомизовать jpg или png изображения без изменения его отображения. Нужно это, чтобы обойти программный контроль одинаковых изображений. Я с графикой на Вы, поэтому буду благодарен за любые советы или примеры.

**update...**

Вот небольшой отрывок из описания алгоритма подобной программы, цитата:

"Что я понял: основа там лежит на световых слоях, что меняется количество световых слоёв, и значит каждый раз меняется слой основной (на этой картинке основной слой 15, на другой картинке он 20). Он показывал световые таблицы картинок, они все разные. Я больше не могу как-то ещё это описать. Насколько понял, так и объяснил."

"Картинки содержат прямоугольники (они все разного цвета). То есть он говорил, что они цвета выстроили в определённые линии и при смещении этих линий для глаза картинка остаётся неизменной, а для робота картинки получаются все разные (сравнил с написанием в коде слова). Можно написать слово сразу целиком, а можно разорвать его по буквам с добавлкением между буквами доп. символов. Мы в тексте будем видеть один и тот же текст, а написание кодов может быть разным, и значит, восприниматься роботом этот текст будет по-разному.
Вроде как-то так)))"

Comment: а как Вы себе представляете "рандомизированное изображение"? переставленные местами блоки? измененные цвета? просто измененный размер?

Comment: А какой алгоритм контроля одинаковых изображений? По какому принципу ваша программа проверки сравнивает и выводит одинаковые изображения?

Comment: Как вариант - изменения заголовка изображений. Там должны быть какие-нибудь описательные поля, куда можно писать любые символы. В итоге по хэшу все картинки будут разные.

Comment: Можно пробовать немного менять цвет каждого пиксела, тогда получится очень похожее изображение

Comment: @z668: Очень зависит от точного алгоритма определения «одинаковости» отображения. Если этот алгоритм будет идеален (то есть, будет считать одинаковыми изображения, которые кажутся одинаковыми для человеческого глаза), то вы в принципе не сможете ничего сделать.

Если вы хотите сообщить какому-то алгоритму, что картинки на самом деле разные, [не пытайтесь обмануть его](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/17/10257351.aspx), а воспользуйтесь официальным API. Если такого нет, посоветуйтесь с разработчиками алгоритма сверки изображений, пусть они посоветуют.

Comment: @VladD, я понял, про что Вы имели ввиду, гонка "Броня vs Снаряд". Идеальных алгоритмов не существует в принципе, сами понимаете. Я не специалист в графике, хотелось бы увидеть\почитать про примерную реализацию алгоритма, который я описал после update... в вопросе. Там, где про световые слои. Очень мало в рунете информации вообще про C# и img.

Comment: Где вы взяли эти световые слои?

Comment: думаю, нужно знакомого и расспрашивать:) но у меня сложилось впечатление, что он что то немного знает, но искаженно. И пытается это рассказать Вам. А тут принцип сломанного телефона работает во всю.

Comment: @KoVadim, Вы абсолютно правы.

Comment: Для JPEG можно записать в EXIF-блок случайные данные, в случае с PNG должно помочь дописывание 8 случайных байт в конец файла.

Comment: @SuperCreeper, это как палить из пугача по бронированному поезду. Возьмем например алгоритмы проверки уникальности картинок на сайте от Яндекса. Вы думаете смена этих данных поможет сделать картинку уникальной?

Comment: @z668, вы для начала расскажите, что за алгоритм сравнения.

Comment: @z668, ну зачем так уродовать вопрос, даже если он вам уже не нужен? Форум-то не только для вас существует, может, кому этот вопрос бы понадобился.

Comment: @DreamChild, ну собственно сам вопрос некорректен. Я действительно не указал алгоритм проверки, т.к. сам его не знаю. Сказали только, что как у Яндекса =) Поэтому решил удалить вопрос.

Comment: @z668, что-то сдается мне, что имеется ввиду бинарное строение изображений, и путь ваш лежит к спецификациям JPEG и PNG изображений (там есть какая-то послойность). А чтение подобных спецификаций нужно только очень узкому кругу программистов, к примеру, которые реализуют рендеринг без помощи готовых средств.